# jOOQ - Render IN as is instead of EXISTS

Tags: java, db2, jooq

I need to query using a "IN" predicate however, jOOQ renders my "IN" as "EXISTS" + 2x nested selects.
However, on DB2, the "IN" is much faster (500ms vs 8s). How can I enforce jOOQ to renders my "IN" predicate exastly the same way as I have describe it through DSL API ?

Sample code :

```
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:")) {
  Settings settings = new Settings().withRenderFormatted(true);
  DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.SQL99, settings);
  ctx
    .createTable("FOOBAR")
    .column("FOO", SQLDataType.INTEGER)
    .column("BAR", SQLDataType.INTEGER)
    .execute();
  String sql = ctx
    .select()
    .from(DSL.tableByName("FOOBAR"))
    .where(
        DSL.row(DSL.fieldByName("FOO")).in(ctx
            .select(DSL.fieldByName("BAR"))
            .from(DSL.tableByName("FOOBAR"))
        )
    )
    .getSQL();
    System.out.println(sql);
}
```

Result:

```
select *
from "FOOBAR"
where exists (
  select "alias_2"."alias_2_0"
  from (
    select "BAR"
    from "FOOBAR"
  ) "alias_2"("alias_2_0")
  where ("FOO") = ("alias_2"."alias_2_0")
)
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the DB2 dialect?

Comment: Why isn't it included in free version ? ;)

Comment: Because our sweat and tears put into making the DB2 integration work must be rewarded!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SQLDialect.SQL99` dialect was not named sensibly. It suggests that it will generate SQL that should run on any database, but that's not correct. It will just generate "default" SQL. This will be corrected in jOOQ 3.6: [#3844](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3844)

In order to optimise SQL generation for use with the DB2 database, you should use the `SQLDialect.DB2` dialect instead. The problem you've encountered here will not be the only one...

Comment: Default and SQL-99 sounds similar to me (at least in this case). When I use "IN", I expect "IN" to be rendered  as default (or as SQL standard).
Is this a wanted limitation in order to "be rewarded" for your great work (and nothing will change) or it's an unexpected behaviour due to "commercial code clean-up" (and it will be fixed) ?

Comment: @mlogan: You should never expect any meaningful output from "SQL99" or "DEFAULT" dialects. It could also just as well be called "UNKNOWN" or "DONTCARE"... I agree that in this case, `IN` should probably be rendered instead, but you shouldn't rely on the rending if "DEFAULT", because that is simply used for `toString()` implementations when debugging (and when no concrete dialect is available).